# rotational differential equation

Tags: equation

An object in 3D space has initial rotation (α_0, β_0, γ_0) (extrinsic Euler rotation).
This object has derivatives (dα/dt, dβ/dt, dγ/dt).

What should the rotation (α, β, γ) be as a function of time?

Comment: The good people over at https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit to answer this question especially if you don't give us any code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.